# Add Image with jOpenDocument in odt document (writer)

Tags: java, api, documentation-generation, odt, jopendocument

I'm trying [jOpenDocument API](http://www.jopendocument.org/) and I want to add/insert an Image. Can I do that with this API? I'm interested in jOpenDocument because it enables me to create a template and then process the document afterwards with Java (which I don't think it's possible with ODFDOM from Apache).

The only thing I found is that I can do something like this:

```
final File outFile = new File("output.odt"); 
final String bcfile = "image.png"; 
final JavaScriptFileTemplate template = new JavaScriptFileTemplate("template.odt"); 
final ODSingleXMLDocument ddoc = template.createDocument(); 
ddoc.getDescendantByName("draw:frame","pC_LSBarcode").setAttribute("href", "file:///" + bcfile,Namespace.getNamespace("xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"));  
ddoc.saveAs(outFile);
```

As you can see this is only an `href` and as result my odt file won't be portable as it depends on the path of the image.

Are there any native methods in jOpenDocument API so I can insert images in my odt document?

Comment: @Krumb I solved this by using BIRT eclipse.org/birt/ you can do pretty much anything with it , you can use data sources from database or JSON, and you can have as an output ODT PDF etc..., it uses JAVA and rhinoscript .

Comment: @Jens were you able to resolve the issue? I am having the same problem

Comment: @Ranjan: we currently use XDocReport for odt / docx processing.